# How to trigger the right conditional statement in a function with conditional arguments

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not sure how to ask my question. I'm not sure my issue is specific to Airflow, to the code shared below... or if it is just me missing something obvious.

I'm working on a Airflow project where I'm importing the following module:

https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/gcs.html

This is the code of the method I want to use from this module:

```
def upload(self, bucket_name: str, object_name: str, filename: Optional[str] = None,
               data: Optional[Union[str, bytes]] = None, mime_type: Optional[str] = None, gzip: bool = False,
               encoding: str = 'utf-8') -> None:
        """
        Uploads a local file or file data as string or bytes to Google Cloud Storage.

        :param bucket_name: The bucket to upload to.
        :type bucket_name: str
        :param object_name: The object name to set when uploading the file.
        :type object_name: str
        :param filename: The local file path to the file to be uploaded.
        :type filename: str
        :param data: The file's data as a string or bytes to be uploaded.
        :type data: str
        :param mime_type: The file's mime type set when uploading the file.
        :type mime_type: str
        :param gzip: Option to compress local file or file data for upload
        :type gzip: bool
        :param encoding: bytes encoding for file data if provided as string
        :type encoding: str
        """
        client = self.get_conn()
        bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)
        blob = bucket.blob(blob_name=object_name)
        if filename and data:
            raise ValueError("'filename' and 'data' parameter provided. Please "
                             "specify a single parameter, either 'filename' for "
                             "local file uploads or 'data' for file content uploads.")
        elif filename:
            if not mime_type:
                mime_type = 'application/octet-stream'
            if gzip:
                filename_gz = filename + '.gz'

                with open(filename, 'rb') as f_in:
                    with gz.open(filename_gz, 'wb') as f_out:
                        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
                        filename = filename_gz

            blob.upload_from_filename(filename=filename,
                                      content_type=mime_type)
            if gzip:
                os.remove(filename)
            self.log.info('File %s uploaded to %s in %s bucket', filename, object_name, bucket_name)
        elif data:
            if not mime_type:
                mime_type = 'text/plain'
            if gzip:
                if isinstance(data, str):
                    data = bytes(data, encoding)
                out = BytesIO()
                with gz.GzipFile(fileobj=out, mode="w") as f:
                    f.write(data)
                data = out.getvalue()
            blob.upload_from_string(data,
                                    content_type=mime_type)
            self.log.info('Data stream uploaded to %s in %s bucket', object_name, bucket_name)
        else:
            raise ValueError("'filename' and 'data' parameter missing. "

                             "One is required to upload to gcs.")
```

and this basically the one line of code invoking this method:

`conn.upload(bucket_name, object_name, data)`

The issue is that even thought I'm passing a variable named `data` I can see that the `upload_from_filename` function is being called when I want to call the `upload_from_string`.

I'm pretty new to python but my comprehension here is that if I'm passing filename argument the `upload_from_filename` function should be called. If I'm passing data argument the `upload_from_string` function should be called.

If I'm not passing anything `conn.upload(bucket_name, object_name)` I have the following error message `filename' and 'data' parameter missing. "` which is expected.

Based on the code I've shared above how do I'm supposed to call the upload method if I want to "switch" to the `upload_from_string` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing positional arguments. The third positional argument is `filename`, so when you pass three positional arguments, the third one goes to `filename`, so `conn.upload()` calls `upload_from_filename()`.

To pass data as a keyword argument, you should use

```py
conn.upload(bucket_name, object_name, data=data)
```

From https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html

There are two kinds of argument:

- keyword argument: an argument preceded by an identifier (e.g. `name=`) in a function call or passed as a value in a dictionary preceded by `**`. For example, 3 and 5 are both keyword arguments in the following calls to complex():

```py
    complex(real=3, imag=5)
    complex(**{'real': 3, 'imag': 5})
```

- positional argument: an argument that is not a keyword argument. Positional arguments can appear at the beginning of an argument list and/or be passed as elements of an iterable preceded by `*`. For example, 3 and 5 are both positional arguments in the following calls:

```py
    complex(3, 5)
    complex(*(3, 5))
```

Comment: Great. It's working... lost a day on this. thanks a lot. How do I know that data should be a positional argument (when filename is a keyword argument...). It is just the logic of it? Or is this something I should find out in the documentation?

Comment: They can _all_ be positional arguments or keyword arguments. The problem with positional arguments is that if you want to specify the 6th argument to the function positionally, you must also specify every argument before it positionally, so you'd end up doing something like `upload(bucket, object, None, data, None, "utf-7")`. Or you could simply do `upload(bucket, object, data=data, encoding="utf-7")`. Mind, you could also specify them all as keyword arguments if you do `upload(bucket_name=bucket, object_name=object, data=data, encoding="utf-7")`

Comment: @SimonBreton If you don't specify the arguments names, they will be assigned by order. Because you want to "skip" the `filename` argument, you have to specify the one that you want, which in this case it is `data=...`

Comment: @SimonBreton You're confused about scopes. The fact the name of your passed variable is the same as a function's argument, doesn't mean anything. These are just names. You either pass arguments by position, or by explicitly specifying which argument you want to assign with `foo(arg=var)`. Even if they have the same name you still have to do `foo(arg=arg)`